# Flex-how to execute a method before loading a screen

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am new to flex and facing a problem and need your help to solve this.

I have some validation errors in some fields of a flex screen.How can I call a method to make the errorString as null to remove error messages from the screen when i load the screen for second time just by clicking a link by the way

```
"Application.application.viewStack.selectedChild = Application.application.myScreen".
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the LifeCycle for that...

But its needed so i am telling you to call the `preinitialize` method of the application. this method is called before the application is initialized....

Have a Nice Day..

Comment: Thanks for response but it is not working for me. In more details i am working on a dashboard on which links to different screens is present. There after getting error on one screen i go to other screen and when I come to the first screen again i want to execute a method before getting the screen and to get a fresh screen but it is loading the old screen with errors.

I am going through your suggestions and kept that preinitialize  method in my mxml file.But it is giving me error of accessing null reference and also not working for me.

Pls Suggest....
Thanks a lot......

Comment: its better that you put your code over here and more specific with your question... and one more thing you need to understand the LifeCycle first and then continue to work... for null reference solution is put your code in creationComplete because this will draw the component on your screen while preinitialize is just method that will call before the initialization of your application...

Please be specific with your question and pus some code in your question to get good answers...

Comment: Hi sagar.....
Good answer...
Please come to chat with Verve system in stack overflow